# How to calculate monthly NDVI raster with R

Tags: r, raster

[NDVI RasterStack](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KyGq3.png)

I have a 15day 1981-2015 NDVI RasterStack.

I need to calculate monthly NDVI with the 15d data.

I want to know how to calculate mean of the same names MM raster into a new monthly 1981-2015 rasterstack

I appreciate for your help! Thank you very much.

[names XYYYY.MM.DD](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Aj9j4.png)

Comment: please provide a *minimal, self-contained, reproducible example* (not files that need to be downloaded). See the help files of the raster package for inspiration.

Answer (score 0):

I have recently been working on the same solution to you problem, this should work for you also.

You want to create a separate variable that contains the dates from your layer names.

```
#this removes the "X" character from the name leaving only the dates

layer_name <- sub('.', '', names(NDVI_stack))

#install.packages("lubridate")
library(lubridate)

layer_name <- ymd(layer_name)

#Create an indices to prepare it for stackApply, which takes the means for all the days of the month within each year.
indices <- format(as.Date(layer_name, format = "%Y.%m.%d"), format = "%Y.m") 

NDVI_mean <- stackApply(NDVI_stack, indices, mean)
```